# What are some good resources on the study of word order?

Tags: reference-request, word-order

I've already read the Wikipedia article on the subject, and I was wondering if any resources exist that go more into detail.

Comment: I recommend first to read two articles by Haspelmath: (1) https://zenodo.org/record/1236544#.Xs0FShNKhQI (2) https://zenodo.org/record/830009#.Xs0E_RNKhQI AND REFERENCES THEREIN (especially the second article).

Comment: You can also read chapter 4 of Language Universals and Linguistic typology by Comrie.

Comment: Thanks for the resource Tsutsu.